# Junit 4 extend TestCase vs using combo of @Before/@After/@Test

Tags: junit4, testcase

With Junit 4 I am seeing that there are two ways of getting fixtures setup/teardown:

1. Decorate setup/tearDown methods with @Before and @After respectively
2. Extend TestCase and override setUp/tearDown

I am trying to understand why two different approaches to doing the same thing. Is it related to option 1 being introduced after Java 5 annotations while `TestCase` is legacy from pre Java 5? Or perhaps I am confusing the two.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The two approaches , as stated [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2635839/junit-confusion-use-extends-testcase-or-test) is because of what is introduced in Junit3 and Junit4. It also talks about why taking annotation way is better and its advantages.

If some of your testcase are wriiten in Junit3 way and now you want to use Junit4 but wondering how this can be done , then please have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17361477/subclass-testcase-and-use-junit-4-annotations).  It is explained there how tests, that are written old way, can be run with Junit4

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Appreciate your help.

Comment: If you think it helped, please don't forget to accept/upvote :)

Comment: I have tried upvoting but site won't allow it. I guess I am not worthy yet of upvoting :-(